# ISBN field not showing with bibliography style "plain"

Tags: bibtex

Why do the contents of the ISBN field not appear?

`\bibliographystyle{plain}`

e.g.

```
@ARTICLE{BS6399,
author={Committee   B/525/1},
journal={BS 6399-2:1997}, title={Loading for buildings. Code of practice for wind loads},
year={1997},
publisher = {BSI},
ISBN     = {0 580 27447 0},
},
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `plain` is an old style. It doesn't know ISBNs. It wouldn't know a field `androidversion` either.

Comment: try deplain.bst from http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/german/  It knows the ISBN field

Comment: @DG' (i) "minimal working" The problem is that it doesn't work.  (ii) it's enough, not need \begin{document}, etc.

Comment: ISO 690 includes ISBN.

Answer (score 2):

There are two [2] reasons for why the `isbn` field isn't showing up:

- The `plain` bibliography style is more than 30 years old. (Yes, really!) As such, `plain` isn't programmed to recognize fields such as `isbn`, `url`, `doi`, `eid`, `issn`, and a few others that are recognized by, say, the `plainnat` bibliography style.
- Using the `@article` entry type is simply wrong for the entry at hand. Moreover, even with the `plainnat` bibliography style the `@article` entry type is not programmed to do anything with a field called `isbn`.

  In `plainnat`, the `@article` entry type does do something with a field called `issn` (International Standard Serial Number) but not with `isbn` (International Standard Book Number).

I suggest you (a) use the `plainnat` bibliography style and (b) change the entry type to `@book`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{BS6399,
author    = {Committee B/525/1},
note      = {BS 6399-2:1997}, 
title     = {Loading for buildings. Code of practice for wind loads},
year      = {1997},
publisher = {BSI},
ISBN      = {0 580 27447 0},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{BS6399}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Optional: Change "BSI" to "British Standards Institute". At least some of your readers will appreciate not having to parse the acronym.